# VLOOKUP formula not detecting correctly

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying but failing to use my VLOOKUP formula, and it is extremely frustrating. Could someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Sheet 1: I have 
[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqBTh.png)

Sheet 2: I have
[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKcvR.png)

If an email address appears in Sheet 2, I would like it to enter the text from column 4 in Sheet 2 into column 8 on Sheet 1.

My current formula entered into H2 on Sheet 1 is:

=VLOOKUP(C2,'Sheet 2'!$A$2:$D$600, 4, FALSE)

This isn't correct - it's telling me that on LOOKUP the value isn't found (even when it is).

Where am I going wrong with my formula?

Thanks

Comment: Use INDEX/MATCH or XLOOKUP - with VLOOKUP, the lookup value has to exist in the *leftmost* column of the lookup table (which is not the case here).

Comment: just begin the region from column c `=VLOOKUP(C2,'Sheet 2'!$C$2:$D$600, 2, 0)`

Comment: you can also use iferror (Anabas's formula, "") for items not found. It will return blank.

Comment: Aaargh, thank you BigBen, that's it of course. The leftmost column. Urgh.